# combine compartors into a single class

Tags: java, oop, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I am using several compartors to sort an ArrayList of object into descending or ascending order. Currenlty, these comparators are in different classes. How can I combine the following comparators into a single class?

```
class ascendingSortComparator implements Comparator<Movie> { //sort movie ascending

    @Override
    public int compare(Movie movie1, Movie movie2) {
        return movie1.getTitle().compareTo(movie2.getTitle());
    }
}

class descendingSortComparator implements Comparator<Movie> { //sort movie ascending

    @Override
    public int compare(Movie movie1, Movie movie2) {
        return -movie1.getTitle().compareTo(movie2.getTitle());
    }
}
```

If this is possible how would I call the appropriate comparator. Currently i'm calling it like:

```
public void sortData() {
    String option = (String) sortComboBox.getSelectedItem();

    if ("Ascending".equals(option)) {
        Collections.sort(movieCatalog, new ascendingSortComparator());
        //indexCount = (movieCatalog.size()-1) - indexCount;
        //displayData(indexCount);
    }

    if ("Descending".equals(option)) {
        Collections.sort(movieCatalog, new descendingSortComparator());
        //indexCount = (movieCatalog.size()-1) - indexCount;
        //displayData(indexCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use an enum

```
public enum MovieComparator implement Comparator<Movie> {
    ASCENDING { //sort movie ascending
        public int compare(Movie movie1, Movie movie2) {
            return movie1.getTitle().compareTo(movie2.getTitle());
        }
    }, DECENDING { 
        public int compare(Movie movie1, Movie movie2) {
            return movie2.getTitle().compareTo(movie1.getTitle());
        }
    }
}

public void sortData() {
    String option = (String) sortComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    MovieComparator cmp = MovieComparator.valueOf(option.toUpperCase());
    Collections.sort(movieCatalog, cmp);
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking: There are three classes: `MovieComparator` and two anonymous classes. But I think this is as close as you can get.

Comment: They can all appear in one Java file and while the implementation means multiple .class files as you say, I think this is the closest to what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe writing a factory of Comparators can be a good idea. Try to see this sample or try to google for more:

http://some-technical-stuff.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the movies in a `TreeSet` (or a `TreeMap`) instead of a `List` and they are sorted at insertion time (you give the `Comparator` as parameter to the constructor). To obtain the reversed movies, simply call `Collections.reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `Comparator<T> Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator<T>)`.

Also I advise not to create new `Comparator` every time, but to allocate them once and then store them.

If you need more sophisticated comparators, Guava's class Ordering could be useful: [Ordering explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained).